# Navigate to a subfolder directly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

This is a very basic question, but was wondering how do you navigate to a subfolder directly without "cd"-ing every level in Jupyter Notebooks? I.e. to get to Documents\Fall 2019\Stack Overflow, I have been entering:

```
cd Documents
cd Fall 2019
cd Stack Overflow
```

but how can I navigate directly to the Stack Overflow folder in one line? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can just enter the command

```
    cd .\Fall 2019\Stack Overflow
```

if that's your question but doesn't jupyter notebooks offer a UI on http://localhost:8888/tree to navigate through repositories why are you using the command line?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me...it returns the message "[WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: I thought you were using Ubuntu

Comment: I still find it kinda useless to use the command line try the UI on http://localhost:8888/tree